# How to turn my doubly linked list container into a "square list" container

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

Hi I have made a doubly linked list container. For a project I now have to turn the doubly linked list into a square list. What I mean by square list is that the data will be stored in a square. So for example 4 elements would be stored like this:

10 30

20 40

5 elements would be stored like this:

10 30 50

20 40

10 elements would be stored like this:

10 40 70 100

20 50 80

30 60 90

Basically the number of rows or columns cannot exceed the square root of the ceiling of the size of the list. What it is meant to do is if there is a large number of data it can insert or erase that data quickly by traversing the columns until it finds the column that the value would be inserting or deleting and then traversing the list from that point until it finds the proper spot to do the insertion or deletion.

What I am thinking about doing is to have the data stored in the doubly linked list and then have a doubly linked list that represents the columns. So each node in the column list will point to where a node in the row list that should represent a column header. How would I go about implementing this?

Here is my doubly linked list container:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class doubleLinkList {

    typedef typename std::size_t        size_type;

private:
    struct rowNode {
        rowNode* prev;
        rowNode* next;
        T data;
        rowNode() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    struct columnNode {
        columnNode* prev;
        columnNode* next;
        T data;
        columnNode() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    struct 

    rowNode* head;
    rowNode* tail;
    unsigned count = 0;

public:
    doubleLinkList();
    ~doubleLinkList();

    void insert(T value);

    size_type size() const { return tail - head; }
    size_type max_size() { return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max(); }

    bool empty() const { return head == tail; };
};

template <typename T> doubleLinkList<T>::doubleLinkList() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = head;
}

template <typename T> doubleLinkList<T>::~doubleLinkList()
{
    while (head)
    {
        rowNode *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

template <typename T> void doubleLinkList<T>::insert(T value) {
    rowNode *node = new rowNode;
    node->data = value;

    // Case 1: There are no nodes yet
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = node;
        tail = head;
        ++count;
        return;
    }

    // Case 2 - Inserting at the head of the list
    if (node->data < head->data)
    {
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        ++count;
        return;
    }

    // Case 3 - Inserting at the end of the list
    if (node->data >= tail->data)
    {
        node->prev = tail;
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
        ++count;
        return;
    }

    // General case - Inserting into the middle
    rowNode* probe = head;
    while (probe && (node->data >= probe->data))
    {
        probe = probe->next;
    }
    if (probe)
    {
        node->next = probe;
        node->prev = probe->prev;
        probe->prev->next = node;
        probe->prev = node;
        ++count;
        return;
    }

    return;
}

template <typename T> bool operator == (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
        return false;
    auto lhp = lhs.begin();
    auto rhp = rhs.begin();
    while (lhp != lhs.end()) {
        if (*lhp++ != *rhp++)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename T> bool operator < (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    auto lhp = lhs.begin();
    auto rhp = rhs.begin();
    while (lhp != lhs.end() && rhp != rhs.end()) {
        if (*lhp < *rhp)
            return true;
        if (*lhp > *rhp)
            return false;
        ++lhp;
        ++rhp;
    }
    if (lhp == lhs.end() && rhp != rhs.end())
        return true;
    return false;
}

template <typename T> inline bool operator != (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

template <typename T> inline bool operator > (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    return rhs < lhs;
}

template <typename T> inline bool operator <= (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs > rhs);
}

template <typename T> inline bool operator >= (doubleLinkList<T> const& lhs, doubleLinkList<T> const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs < rhs);
}

int main() {
    doubleLinkList<int> list;
    list.insert(10);
    list.insert(20);
    list.insert(15);
    list.insert(25);
}
```

Comment: How would *square list* work for insertion/deletion ? Most node would require changes...

Comment: I guess it would work like this. For each insertion I would look at the size of the list and then find the square root of the size. Then look at the ceiling (so the ceiling for the square root of 3 is 2. That means that I can use 2 rows and 2 columns. Then lets say the size of the list is 5, it's ceiling would be 3 so there can be 3 rows and 3 columns. So each time the ceiling changes, I have to change around the header list.

So to insert I traverse the header list until I find data that is less than the data the header is pointing to.

Comment: Can you just store things in a doubly linked list and just output/display things as a square list as needed?

Comment: I wish! It has to insert and erase in square root time.